# attempt to index nil with "WaitForChild"

Tags: lua, roblox

i am making a game right now and i want enemies that spawn to have a health bar + player base.
All i have been giving this function to has a humanoid. but it will not stop saying attempt to index nil with wait for child at line 16. (This is a module script located in replicated)

```
 local Players = game:GetService("Players")
 local health = {}

function health.Setup(model)
    local newHealthBar = script.HealthGui:Clone()
    newHealthBar.Adornee = model:WaitForChild("Head")
    newHealthBar.Parent = Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui
   health.UpdateHealth()
    model.Humanoid.HealthChanged:Connect(function()
        health:UpdateHealth(newHealthBar, model)
    end)
end

function health.UpdateHealth(gui, model)
    local humanoid = model:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

    if humanoid and gui then
        local percent = humanoid.Health / humanoid.MaxHealth
        gui.CurrentHealth.Size = UDim2.new(percent, 0, 0.5, 0)
        if humanoid.Health <= 0 then
            gui.Title.Text = model.Name .. "Has died"
        else
            gui.Title.Text = "Health:" .. humanoid.Health .. "/" .. humanoid.MaxHealth
        end
    end
end

return health
```

Answer (score 0):

In `health.Setup` you call `health.UpdateHealth()` so in `health.UpdateHealth` `gui` and `model` are nil values.

That's why `local humanoid = model:WaitForChild("Humanoid")` is causing the observed error.

If you don't provide any arguments to a function all its parameters are nil. nil values may not be indexed as in `model:WaitForChild("Humanoid")` which is syntactic sugar for `model["WaitForChild"](model, "Humanoid")` where `model["WaitForChild"]` is the indexing operation.

Comment: so how do i fix it? (i am not the best scripter)

Comment: call it with proper arguments or don't call it.  I don't see a reason for that function call. what do you want to achieve with it?
if you don't know how to fix this you should do some Lua tutorials befor trying to use a complex game development framework like Roblox.